# R matching error after changing input data set

Tags: r, matching

I have a long script that sorts things and finds unique items. Everything was functioning fine until I added more data to my database. Then things started breaking.  I've gone back and cleaned up my database to fix some errors, but my code is now failing elsewhere. And I cant figure out why.

Error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "type", value = character(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 144
```

happens at:

```
OPdf$"type" <- IPdf$"type"[OPdf$"name"==IPdf$"name"]
```

IPdf: (two columns of characters)

```
#   type    name
1   ball    Test-7
2   square  bob-allen
3   cat     HHH_67
4   groot   765-6
```

OPdf: (one column of factors)

```
 #     name
 1     bob-allen
 2     765-6
 3     HHH_67
 4     Test-7
```

I have the same number of rows in each dataframe. I can call my original test set of data into the script and everything works fine. I have verified that there aren't any weird characters in my names column that would throw something off.

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Those are probably factors which are really integer vectors whose value is determined by the items at construction. Learn to use as.character before testing equality or membership. (I don't think it derives from the superfluous use of double quotes around column names.) BUT as always error reports require data input for accurate commentary. Voting to close.

Comment: I've tracked the problem down to earlier in the code to where my database is returning data in a different order than i requested it. Which results in one of these lists not being in the same order as the other. That's what is causing the error.